# Aptana "Show in Project Explorer" shortcut

Tags: aptana3

What is the shortcut for showing the current file in the project explorer?

Even better: is there a way to make the current file automatically show in project explorer tree? Visual Studio and SublimeText (via SyncedSidebar plugin) have this functionality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the current file show in the Project Explorer by clicking on the little arrow at the top right of the Project Explorer and choosing 'Link with Editor'.